# How to avoid python termination against external dll crash?

Tags: python-3.x, dll, kernel, ctypes, spyder

I have loaded the ngspice shared spice circuit simulator (dll) in python using ctypes. I am running my simulations in the background thread of ngspice and I call ngspice_running() function to see if the simulation is still running.

So the problem is that when sometimes I input a wrong circuit, the program crashes. I think since I am still calling ngspice_running() function to check the status of the background thread, it makes my python kernel to die. I am using python exception statements to keep my program running but it is not so helpful in this case I guess.

How could I avoid this kernel death issue to keep my python program running as I cannot avoid inputting some wrong circuits? It would be great if someone could point me to the right direction.

Is there some way by which the program could return to certain line of code in python in case of external error from where the program cannot recover?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you calling the func in a background *Python* thread? Could you post some code and data in order to reproduce the problem? Also is *ngspice*  downloadable by anyone? Did you also try to reproduce the problem from *C*? Generally in a situation like this you're doing smth wrong, maybe there is a func that checks validity of a circuit without crashing (or maybe you're just passing wrong arguments), or maybe you're not supposed to use that func this way. But it's too much to guess from too little provided.

Comment: No, I am calling the function in python main thread which runs the simulation in a background thread of ngspice circuit simulator and returns immediately to python main thread. I then check the status of the background simulation by calling a another function to wait for the simulation to complete. I am actually trying to generate the circuits automatically so in the initial phase some components are not connected together. The crashing of the ngspice circuit simulator is random but let me get back with a reproducible example.

Comment: Here, I have uploaded an example on github:  https://github.com/APCG/Kernel-Death-example-with-ngspice.git